# Visual Studio Terminal Configuration Problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying hard to configure Git bash for the visual studio terminal, but my visual studio did not detect the git bash files even after I put it in PATH. I've followed many tutorials but still, it seems not to be working.Here I'll show some of the terminal settings.json and the problems I'm facing [Visual Studio Settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJGYn.jpg)

Comment: There is a known issue about this.  Are you using the latest v1.57 of vscode?  If not, try upgrading and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @Mark yes im using the v1.57 version i still can't see git bash option in the new terminal button i already reinstall vs code so many times :(

Comment: Click on the `+` for a new terminal - is it bash terminal?  If so, kill the other one you don't want.  Then close and restart vscode - that seemed to help me.

Comment: Pictures need to be posted inside your question. You can still edit them in, by clicking the edit button.

Comment: This is why I use linux

Comment: @Mark i've kill it so many times and refresh it but nothing seems to be working.